# Session Id apperaing in FireFox and not in IE 9

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, session

My aspx web application is working fine in both IE 9 and in FireFox, however,
The session is being displayed in the URL when viewed from FireFox but not in IE 9.
Why is the session id being displayed. Do i need to configure anything on the IIS. Please advise

```
IE 9:    htttp://XXXXXXXXXXX.com/Welcome.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
FireFox: htttp://XXXXXXXXXXX.com/(SESSION ID)Welcome.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie is disabled in the FireFox browser. We need to enable to cookies in order to hide the  Session Id.